# How to find a controller using GetX in flutter

Tags: flutter-getx

I am trying to use Get.find to use LessonListController, but flutter tells me error,

throw '"$S" not found. You need to call "Get.put($S())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>$S())"'

below is Lessonlistcontroller

```
class LessonListController extends GetxService {
  final LessonListRepo lessonListRepo;

  LessonListController({required this.lessonListRepo});
  List<dynamic> _lessonList = [];
  List<dynamic> get lessonList => _lessonList;

  Future<void> getLessonList() async {
    Response response = await lessonListRepo.getLessonList();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('got you');
      _lessonList = [];
      _lessonList.addAll(Course.fromJson(response.body).lessons);
      // update();
      //update
    } else {}
  }
}
```

dependencies as below,

```
Future<void> init() async {
  //api client
  Get.lazyPut(() => ApiClient(appBaseUrl: AppConstants.BASE_URL));

  //repos
  Get.lazyPut(() => LessonListRepo(apiClient: Get.find()));

  //controllers
  Get.lazyPut(() => LessonListController(lessonListRepo: Get.find()));
}
```

here is the main.dart file

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.find<LessonListController>().getLessonList();
    // Get.lazyPut<LessonListController>(() =>get.() {

    // };

    return const GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Diary(),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I solved this issue, the Get.find<LessonListController>().getLessonList(); is not right, should be like final LessonListController lessonlistController =
      Get.put(LessonListController());

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the **LessonListController** using **Get.put(LessonListController())**;

Get.find() is used to get the already initialized instance of Created controller.

GetxControlled works as Singleton, So it finds the already created instance every time you call Get.find() ,  Get.find() will only work if you have previously called Get.put or Get.lazyPut

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that with the help of tag.

```
Get.put(CategoryController(), tag: "controller1");
Get.find<CategoryController>(tag:'controller1');
```

But make sure you have initialized the controller with the tag name.